# Estimating Start and End season for each pixel using NDVI timeseries in R

Tags: r, raster, terra, satellite-image

Problem: A raster stack has 4 months of NDVI data. I need to do following:

1. Find peak of each cell.
2. Find min threshold values for before and after peak.
3. Make all cells before and after minimum defined value to zero

Here is the sample code:

```
library(terra)

r <- rast(ncols=2, nrows=2)

r1 <- setValues(r, c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5))
r2 <- setValues(r, c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2))
r3 <- setValues(r, c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5))
r4 <- setValues(r, c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7))
r5 <- setValues(r, c(0.8,1,1,0.6))
r6 <- setValues(r, c(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.5))
r7 <- setValues(r, c(0.6,0.6,0.6,0.5))
r8 <- setValues(r, c(0.9,0.4,0.4,0.4))
r9 <- setValues(r, c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2))
r10 <- setValues(r, c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1))

s <- c(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10)
names(s) <- c('1L','2L','3L','4L','5L','6L','7L','8L','9L','10L')

f<-function(x){
  if(!is.na(x[1])){
    index <- which.max(x)
    maxvalue <- x[index]
    
    t1 <- maxvalue * 0.3
    t2 <- maxvalue * 0.3
    
    st <- which(x[1:index] < t1)
    last_st <- st[length(st)]
    x[1:last_st] <- 0
    
    en <- which(x[index:length(x)] < t2)
    first_en <- length(x) - en[1] + 2
    x[first_en:length(x)] <- 0
    }
  x
  print(x)
}

ss=app(s,f)
```

Now this works fine in certain cases but fails if peak value is at very 1st cell. And why this loop runs 6 times. Making values zero after 2nd minimum value doesn't make sense. I did some arithmetics with index values but this doesn't seem right.